# ImageResizer Losing Transparency

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am using ImageResizer from imageresizing.net and I am having a problem with transparency. When I resize png images, I am losing transparency and ending up with a black background.Here is my code, if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
var imagejob = new ImageJob();

imagejob.Instructions = new Instructions();

imagejob.Instructions.Width = 400;
imagejob.Instructions.Height = 300;
imagejob.Instructions.Mode = ImageResizer.FitMode.Max;
imagejob.Instructions.Format = "png";
imagejob.Instructions.OutputFormat = ImageResizer.OutputFormat.Png;
imagejob.Source = inStream;
imagejob.Dest = outStream;

ImageBuilder.Current.Build(imagejob);

FinalWidth = Convert.ToInt32(imagejob.FinalWidth);
FinalHeight = Convert.ToInt32(imagejob.FinalHeight);

BytesToSaveToDB = outStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this, I have found the answer. The code i posted works fine and keeps transparency, I was using that code for resizing upon upload. I was actually then resizing the image again when displaying the image which i had not realised, and it was when displaying the image i was using the old code to resize which did not maintain transparency. So i was resizing twice and he old code was causing the issue, so the code i posted actually works fine.